# CMFCTabCtrl color customising

Tags: colors, tabs, mfc, color-scheme

Is there the way to change the line and background colors of `CMFCBaseTabCtrl`?

I can change tabs color via `SetTabBkColor(...)` or `SetAutoColors(...)` but control's header and lines remain grey.

`SetSysColors(...)` is not an option because it changes colors globally for entire OS.

Basically we need to apply some lite/dark color scheme. I can not find the way to change tab control background and line colors. When the tab background color is set by `SetTabBkColor(...)` it leaves the space near the tab border.

Also its expected that `SetActiveTabColor(...)` will change the background of the active tab but it does pretty nothing.

And there is no way to change the text color of the active tab. I belive this stuff is customisable but can not find how.

[image]

Comment: You have to be more specific. CMFCBaseTabCtrl doesn't contain any code for drawing. What element you want to change?

Comment: I need to apply dark color scheme to the entire stuff. I have added the image above which shows what is required.

Comment: Again! This isn't a CMFCBaseTabCtrl this must be something derived from CMFCBaseTabCtrl! What kind of Tab Ctrl is it? CMFCBaseTabCtrl is a base class a pure virtual functions... Please refine your question!

Comment: the class is derived from CMFCTabCtrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors are retrieved from the current instance of the CMFCVisualManager.

CMFCVisualManager::GetTabFrameColors is used. And some other manager functions like OnEraseTabsFrame and OnEraseTabsArea.

So derive your own visual manager from the one you prefer. Overwrite the specific functions and so you can change the colors and behavior.

There is no other way. Just lok into the source code in void CMFCTabCtrl::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\afxtabctrl.cpp

Comment: yep, I see. however these colors are used for drawing lines not 3d highlights of the tabs. Actual tab is drawn by CMFCVisualManager::OnDrawTab(...). So I will need impement own manager that overrides these 4 methods.

Comment: Just tried some workaround, to modify afxGlobalData.clrBarHilite, 
afxGlobalData.clrBarShadow and afxGlobalData.clrBarDkShadow. It works for lines but not for fill. So there is no easy way.